# how to create nested schema in nestjs use mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, schema, nestjs-mongoose

- email
- password
- role
- confirmed
- id
- address

  - city
  - street

My user schema should be like this. I want it to appear as a nested schema. separate the address space.

```
export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  role: { type: String, enum: Role, default: Role.USER },
  confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  id: { type: String, default: uuid.v4 },
});

UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  try {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) {
      return next();
    }
    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(this['password'], 10);
    this['password'] = hashed;
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

**interface user**

```
export interface User extends Document {
   id:string;
   email: string;
   password: string;
   role: Role[];
   address: ?
}
```

I have to add the address in user. How?

```
  export const AddrSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
      city: { type: String, default: "bb" },
      street: { type: String, default: "aa" },
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve it.

```
 export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
   password: { type: String, required: true },
   role: { type: String, enum: Role, default: Role.USER },
   confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
   id: { type: String, default: uuid.v4 },
   address: { 
     city: { type: String, default: "bb" },
     street: { type: String, default: "aa" },
   }
  });
```

Comment: Fields in it are not added (street , city vs).  just appearing " address: array " . do i need to update the interface ? Unfortunately, the inside of the address field is not formed.

Comment: see my updated answer maybe it will help.

Comment: not like this, but I want it to appear on separate schema